# How to calculate the position of a range defined by "offset", without VBA?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose I have a calculation in cell A3 based on Offset:

```
 = STDEV(OFFSET(H30,1-M2,0,M2,1))
```

since using of offset will not make the range visible when I click on the cell, I'd like to add a couple of checkings to ensure the calculation is alway correct.

Now, how could I show the top row, left column, row count and column count of the range defined by this `OFFSET(H30,1-M2,0,M2,1)`?

can this be done using Excel formula only, without adopting VBA?

Comment: Row count is M2 and column count is always 1. Top-left cell address is `ADDRESS(ROW(OFFSET(H30,1-M2,0,M2,1)),COLUMN(OFFSET(H30,1-M2,0,M2,1)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming M2 contains a positive number won't the range always end at H30? (or if M2 is negative range will **start** at H32). You could get the full address with this formula

`=CELL("address",OFFSET(H30,1-MAX(M2,SIGN(M2)),0))&":"&CELL("address",OFFSET(H30,1-MIN(M2,SIGN(M2)),0))`

Answer (score 3):

Full address:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(OFFSET(H30,1-M2,0,M2,1)),COLUMN(OFFSET(H30,1-M2,0,M2,1))) & ":" &
 ADDRESS(ROW(OFFSET(H30,1-M2,0,M2,1))+ROWS(OFFSET(H30,1-M2,0,M2,1))-1,
 COLUMN(OFFSET(H30,1-M2,0,M2,1))+COLUMNS(OFFSET(H30,1-M2,0,M2,1))-1)
```

Credit to Richard Schollar: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/506397-formula-show-full-address-named-range-without-visual-basic-applications.html